# Altenative accessible web input control

Tags: html, web, accessibility

#### My issue

I would like to use [select2](https://select2.org/) (with ajax) on my website. However, I've noticed that it doesn't seem to be compatible with screen reader systems, which is a drawback.

The challenge I'm facing revolves around finding a solution for this issue. While select2 enhances the visual user experience, it falls short in terms of accessibility for individuals relying on screen readers.

#### My Attempted Solution

I've made an attempt to address this by employing two components: one designed for screen readers and another exclusively for visual purposes. Here's a snippet of how I envisioned it:

```html
<!-- WARNING NON VALID HTML -->
<div aria-hidden="true">
   <my_not_accessible_select2_control_with_ajax />
</div>

<div class="visually-hidden">
   <select name="my_accessible_set_of_alt_selects"></select>
</div>
```

But, this is not a solution because focusable content don't be tagged as `aria-hidden="true"`.

How can I deal with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Before you try using two components, can you explain what fails with select2 with respect to accessibility? Is it just a screen reader issue or could the failure happen for other users too? If the latter, then having separate components might not help some users. [Github for select2](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues?q=is%3Aissue+nvda+) shows that some bugs with "NVDA" in the text have been closed and some are still open so the devs appear willing to work on accessibility issues. (I randomly picked "NVDA" to search for bugs.)

Comment: There's also a [select2 forum](https://forums.select2.org/) and I saw an [accessibility related question](https://forums.select2.org/t/a11y-screen-reader-reads-the-text-input-rather-than-option-values/206) so you may want to search there too.

Comment: Thanks @slugolicious, I have noticed it's not compatible because I tried it with VoiceOver and the screen reader [don't read options](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3735). But fix select2 is not the focus of my question. Really, I don't know what I'm asking for. Maybe, how to deal with alternative focusable control for a11y. Thanks about your comments.

Comment: *"But fix select2 is not the focus of my question"*. But it should be. If there is an accessibility issue, the **first** course of action should be to try to fix the code. The **last** course of action is to find an alternative component and offer different components to different users. Alt components are allowed by WCAG but it really is the last choice. You have to guarantee that the functionality of the two components is the same. If you add a new feature to one, you have to add it to the other. You'll have dual maintenance. And how do you decide which users should have the alt component?

Comment: @slugolicious, _'Alt components are allowed by WCAG but it really is the last choice.'_ Can you explain how to do it? Thanks